# circlize::circos.heatmap Add gaps between cells

Tags: r, heatmap, circlize, circos

I am creating a circular heatmap as follows:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(circlize) 
})

# input data
dput(annot)

structure(list(Specimen_Type = c("Both", "Plasma", "Both", "Both", 
"Plasma", "Plasma", "Plasma", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Plasma", 
"Plasma", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", 
"Both", "Both", "Plasma", "Both", "Both", "Plasma", "Both", "Plasma", 
"Plasma", "Both", "Plasma", "Both", "CSF", "Both", "Plasma", 
"Both", "Both", "Both", "Plasma", "Both", "Plasma", "Both", "Plasma", 
"Plasma", "Both", "Both", "Plasma", "Both", "Both", "Plasma", 
"Plasma", "Plasma", "Plasma", "Plasma", "Both", "Both"), Sex = c("Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female")), row.names = c("15635-29", "15635-31", "15635-32", 
"15635-37", "15635-38", "15635-182", "15635-42", "15635-43", 
"15635-45", "15635-46", "15635-53", "15635-215", "15635-58", 
"15635-60", "15635-63", "15635-68", "15635-70", "15635-75", "15635-80", 
"15635-81", "15635-87", "15635-90", "15635-100", "15635-101", 
"15635-108", "15635-120", "15635-127", "15635-129", "15635-132", 
"15635-134", "15635-135", "15635-1", "15635-2", "15635-251", 
"15635-7", "15635-11", "15635-145", "15635-148", "15635-150", 
"15635-154", "15635-156", "15635-158", "15635-161", "15635-169", 
"15635-170", "15635-187", "15635-197", "15635-214", "15635-228", 
"15635-225", "15635-246", "15635-254", "15635-234", "15635-239", 
"15635-279"), class = "data.frame")

split <- factor(annot$Specimen_Type)
col_fun1 <- list("Male" = "navy",
                 "Female" = "deeppink4",
                 'Plasma' = '#fcff5c',
                 'CSF' = '#8d14ff',
                 'Both' = '#14f9ff')
circos.par(start.degree = 30, gap.degree = 1, points.overflow.warning = FALSE)
circos.heatmap(annot, 
               split = split, 
               col = unlist(col_fun1), 
               track.height = 0.4, 
               bg.border = "gray50", bg.lty = 1.5,
               show.sector.labels = T)
circos.clear()
```

How do I add gaps between individual cells in the heatmap?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update the circlize package and add `cell.border = "white"` param.